# How to make sure open code files in Visual Studio don't corrupt during a sudden shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, crash, shutdown, file-corruption, visual-studio-2015

Often when my computer suddenly shuts down / crashes and I have VS open, 1 or 2 open files in it will be filled with hexadecimal zeros or garbage. This is a problem because currently my computer currently crashes semi-frequently and I'm not able to get it fixed quite yet, and I still have to work on things in VS. I'm not talking about the computer crashing during saving, I just mean that having them open when a sudden shutdown occurs can cause some sort of corruption to random open files. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening? Maybe something like Sublime Text's atomic save or automatic backups? (can't find an option for that in VS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting into whether read-access can thrash open files, perhaps the problem is related to write caching. Write caching can make the system "peppy" by deferring actual writes to the drive, but in the case of power outages etc, you can get data loss.

I think the default for windows is having write-caching enabled for internal HDDs. You might try disabling write-caching.

Comment: What other effects will this cause?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I suppose write-caching could be thought of like the print spooler on much smaller time scales. I suspect the performance impact is not that big, excepting perhaps shutdown or big write operations. I suspect all of this is implementation specific. In any event it is an easily toggled options that potentially improves data integrity and you will at least eliminate a possible point of failure for troubleshooting.

Comment: One thing though: do not turn off "write cache buffer flushing" as this makes the write caching even lazier and more dangerous for data. It is on the same property page as write caching, but is a setting that modifies the behavior of enabled write caching.